# printing a number and writing in ipython interpreter gives different outputs

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

t is array of two `float64` numbers. 
On typing `t` in Ipython 2.7, it is giving following output:

```
array([ 60.211127, 71.08120185])
```

`print t` gives

```
[ 60.211127, 71.08120185]
```

`print t[0]` gives

```
60.211127
```

but...
`t[0]` gives

```
60.211126999999998
```

as an output.

P.S.

```
from decimal import *
Decimal(t[0])
```

gives

```
Decimal('60.21112699999999762212610221467912197113037109375')
```

as output.Why is it happening so?

Comment: `print` uses the `str` format, plain interactive `out` uses the `repr` version.  Add on top of that the different display conventions for `array` (`numpy`?) and Python floats.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I think you are having is because there is no way to approximate some values in some data formats. (the same way you can't show 1/3 because you would just have .3333333333333... forever) There is more info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

a useful function might be `repr()` more info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)